# Extracting numbers from midpoint of string (R)

Tags: r

I have 5 character long strings like

```
vec <- c("1.345", "123.5", ".234." "..345", "..3.5")
```

How can I extract the full number connected to the middle character, giving results 345,123,234,345,3?

Most of the numbers are 3 digits long, so I had been using str_extract_all and max, which works for the first 4 entries but fails at entry 5, I can't seem to find a regex that does what I want. Is this possible using regex?

Answer (score 2):

With this regex:

`(?<=^.{0,2})` positive lookbehind looks that there are up to two characters before the match

`[0-9]+`       one or more digits.

`(?=.{0,2}$)`  again positive lookahead looks that there are up to two characters after the match

```
library(stringr)

vec <- c("1.345", "123.5", ".234.", "..345", "..3.5")

str_extract(vec, "(?<=^.{0,2})[0-9]+(?=.{0,2}$)")
```

```
[1] "345" "123" "234" "345" "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` and raw strings.

```
> sub(r"{\d*?\.*?(\d*)\.?\d?$}", '\\1', vec, perl=TRUE)
[1] "345" "123" "234" "345" "3"
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(vec)
c("1.345", "123.5", ".234.", "..345", "..3.5")
```